# Solve the Euler Angle equations

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, symbolic

I'm trying to solve the system of equations, but I have no idea what wrong with my code.

I wanna find out the relationship between $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\alpha1$, $\beta1$, $\gamma1$,$\alpha2$, $\beta2$, $\gamma2$ 
. How can I come to the same conclusion. Should I use Reduce rather than Solve?
Can you tell me?

thank you.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
SetAttributes[{α1, β1, γ1, α2, β2, γ2}, Constant];
FindInstance[
 And @@ Thread[EulerMatrix[{α, β, γ}] == 
    EulerMatrix[{α1, β1, γ1}].EulerMatrix[{α2, β2, γ2}]], {α, β, γ}]
```

finally, the result:

```
Cos[β]->Cos[β1] Cos[β2] - Sin[β1] Sin[β2]Cos[α2+γ1] 
Tan[α-α1] -> ?
Tan[γ-γ2] -> ?
```